# How to get random string from database?

Tags: android, sql

I'm working on application, in which first activity gets random value from database and sends it to the next activity as a string.

I know exactly how this can be done in sql:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

After some attempts to use it in app I've come to this:

```
Cursor send = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_NAME }, null, null, null, null, "RANDOM() LIMIT 1");

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("description", send.getString(send.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)));
```

But I got error on the last line after pressing button to open the second activity.

---

**Added Log:**

```
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:400)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259): at com.example.ListAction$1.onItemClick(ListAction.java:90)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1177)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2705)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3458)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
05-22 22:14:24.202: E/AndroidRuntime(14259):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Keyser `E/AndroidRuntime(14259): at com.example.ListAction$1.onItemClick(ListAction.java:90)`. 90th line is `b.putString("description", send`

Comment: Here's the relevant part: `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1`

Comment: You might need to do "getColumnIndex" - 1 (add `-1`), but I actually have no idea.

Comment: @Keyser Unfortunately, this is not the solution. But thanks anyway. I will try to rebuild the application and make it simplier to better understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `ORDER BY RANDOM()` isn't usually all that great in terms of performance.  Why not generate a (random) number application side, and ask for that entry?  If you aren't guaranteed that one, get some (small) range, and ask for the 'top' one.  Should probably perform better.

Comment: @X-Zero it's a good idea. It solves some of my problems. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you should point your cursor to the first row. I have not found this in your code:

```
if (!send.moveToFirst()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Cannot move to first row of the Cursor!");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rawQuery` instead:

```
database.rawQuery("SELECT column 
                   FROM table 
                   ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",null);
```

You'd get the same type of `cursor` but executing the query as you'd normally do in sql.

So **assuming** your second portion of the code is correct:

```
Cursor send =database.rawQuery("SELECT column 
                   FROM table 
                   ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",null);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("description", send.getString(send.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)));
```

Comment: The method rawQuery(String, String[]) is not applicable for the arguments (String). What should I write instead of String[]?

Comment: Note the second argument `,null` after the rawQuery. 
I'll update the format so it's easier to see

Comment: Ok, thanks. The problem still exists, but your code looks like a solution. I'll try to simplify the app and use this code.